# How to ensure a variable is not garbage collected?

Tags: java, spring, garbage-collection, jvm

Below controller exposes two endpoints.

"generateRec" populates a `HashMap<String, Set<String>>`

"getRecById" returns the value of Map populated by "generateRec"

I'd like to persist the value of rec within the jvm and so do not want it to be garbage collected.

I don't think `rec` will be garbage collected since it is never set to null ?

Here is the controller :

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("getResponse")
public class RecController {

     private static Map<String, Set<String>> rec = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

     @RequestMapping(value = "/generateRec" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
     @ResponseBody
     public String generateRec(){

       rec = getRec();

      return getAsHtml(rec);
     }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/getRecById" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
     @ResponseBody
     public String getRecById(@RequestParam String id){

         if(rec.containsKey(id)){
             return rec.get(id).toString();
         }
         else {
             return "id "+id+ " not found"; 
         }

     }

     private String getAsHtml(Map<String, java.util.Set<String>> rec){
          String recStr = "";
          for(String key : rec.keySet()){

              recStr += key + " -> " + rec.get(key)+ "<br>";
          }

          return recStr;
     }

}
```

Update :

Answering questions in comments :

Why do you want to "persist the value of rec within the jvm"? 
populating "rec" is an expensive operation and determining when it should be populated is decided by invoking "/generateRec" endpoint. I've updated question to read "rec = getRec();" . I guess I'm trying to implement a very basic cache.

How do you expect to use it again?
rec will be utilized when "getRecById" endpoint is invoked

Comment: Just keep a strong reference pointing to the variable..works in most cases...

Comment: *Why* do you want to "persist the value of rec within the jvm"? How do you expect to use it again? If you've got a reference to it, it won't be GC'd... and if you haven't, then you wouldn't be able to get back to it anyway. (This is all modulo weak references...)

Comment: Not that there would be much to garbage collect from this empty Map.

Comment: @JonSkeet ive answered your questions in updated question. So since ive a reference to rec via a static instance it will never be GC'd ?

Comment: Yes. The object won't be collected while a static variable refers to it.

Comment: @JonSkeet what is meant by "modulo weak references" ?

Comment: Afraid to be off topic but your code seems *strange*. As a Spring controller is normally a singleton bean what is the mean of having `rec`to be static ? And I hope you noticed that if you have many sessions, all will use the same `rec`...

Comment: @blue-sky: I mean that if you use weak references, my simplistic statement becomes less true. Search for "weak reference" for more information.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta ah yes, since the controller itself is a singleton and will not be GC'd , members of same controller will not be GC'd